# Multiple group analysis in canonical correlation analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, effect-size, group-differences, canonical-correlation

Canonical correlation analysis estimates the relationship between two canonical sets of variables. However, I am interested in using a technique to compare these CCA results across groups (something akin to a multiple-group analysis in SEM). I am having difficulty finding literature on this specific method. Much of the information is about CCA for more than two canonical sets, but that is not what I am interested in.

A driving example: say I am interested in examining the relationship between Big 5 personality (1st canonical set) and a set of resiliency scales (2nd canonical set). I also want to compare these CCA results between male and female participants. As such, I am looking to find significance tests and effect size comparisons of my CCA results (standardized and structure coefficients, canonical r, etc..). Is there an established approach for this that I am just using the wrong names/descriptors to find?

Comment: Canonical correlation is very similar to SEM, which lets you do multiple group comparisons: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10705519709540060. Since that was written explorary SEM has come into existence, which might be even better.